# Solving a system of linear equations with constraints

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried to look for questions similar to mine but I couldn't find any.

My goal is to solve the following system of equations:

$$\begin{align*}
-3a+\frac12 b+\frac32 c+\frac94&=p\\
-\frac12 a-\frac14 b-\frac34 c&=q\\
\frac12 a+\frac14 b+\frac34 c+\frac32&=r\\
-\frac12 a-\frac14 b-\frac34 c+\frac14&=s\\
-\frac12 a-\frac14 b-\frac34 c+\frac34&=t
\end{align*}$$

With $a, b, c$ non-negative integers and $p,q,r,s,t$ rationals non-integers.

My attempt to tackle the problem was the following:

```
Reduce[-3*a + b/2 + 3*c/2 + 9/4 == p  
    && -a/2 - b/4 - 3*c/4 == q  
    && 3/2 + a/2 + b/4 + 3*c/4 == r  
    && 1/4 - a/2 - b/4 - 3*c/4 == s  
    && 3/4 - a/2 - b/4 - 3*c/4 == t  
    && Element[a, Integers]  
    && Element[b, Integers]  
    && Element[c, Integers]  
    && NotElement[p, Integers]  
    && NotElement[q, Integers]  
    && NotElement[r, Integers]  
    && NotElement[s, Integers]  
    && NotElement[t, Integers]  
    && a >= 0  
    && 0 <= b  
    && 0 <= c,  
    {a, b, c, p, q, r, s, t}, Rationals]
```

But the result I get is just a rewriting of the same equations without any explicit constraints.

The point is that I have reasons to believe that there are no solutions to this system but then I would have expected the answer: `False`.

Therefore I would like to know if I wrote down the code correctly and if there is a way to understand if there are solutions to the system.

Comment: It's overdetermined (five equations vs. three unknowns), no?

Comment: actually also the p, q, r, s, t are free, so is more like five equations eight unknowns

Comment: As far as I can tell there are no solutions that meet you constraints that all of `p, q, r, s, t` be non-integers. If you allow at least one of them to be an integers there seem to infinitely many solutions.

Comment: That is exactly my point. But I would like to be sure of it.

Comment: To be more clear. I have a priori reasons to think that there are no solutions if I put all of those constraints. Moreover, I tried some do cycles as a check and it seems that an integer  always pops out. However even if I'm pretty convinced of the absence of the solutions I don't know how to prove it and I was hoping that mathematica could provide me an answer.

Comment: I deleted my answer, because regarding rationals as quotients of Integers doesn't proove anything, since Integers are also rationals. One of the parameters p,q,r,s,t,  always seems to be an Integer. Didn't find a proof of the contrary.

Answer (score 2):

Start with a straightforward `Solve`:

```
firstsol = 
 FullSimplify[
  Solve[-3*a + b/2 + 3*c/2 + 9/4 == p && -a/2 - b/4 - 3*c/4 == q && 
    3/2 + a/2 + b/4 + 3*c/4 == r && 1/4 - a/2 - b/4 - 3*c/4 == s && 
    3/4 - a/2 - b/4 - 3*c/4 == t && Element[a, Integers] && 
    Element[b, Integers] && Element[c, Integers] && 
    NotElement[p, Integers] && NotElement[q, Integers] && 
    NotElement[r, Integers] && NotElement[s, Integers] && 
    NotElement[t, Integers] && a >= 0 && 0 <= b && 0 <= c, {a, b, c, 
    p, q, r, s, t}, Rationals], 
  Element[(a | b | c), Integers] && a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0]
```

which gives you an error telling you that you have more unknowns than equations, along with

```
(*
{{p -> ConditionalExpression[1/4 (9 - 12 a + 2 b + 6 c), 
    1/4 (-2 a - b - 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (1 - 2 a - b - 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (3 - 2 a - b - 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (6 + 2 a + b + 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (9 - 12 a + 2 b + 6 c) \[NotElement] Integers], 
  q -> ConditionalExpression[1/4 (-2 a - b - 3 c), 
    1/4 (-2 a - b - 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (1 - 2 a - b - 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (3 - 2 a - b - 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (6 + 2 a + b + 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (9 - 12 a + 2 b + 6 c) \[NotElement] Integers], 
  r -> ConditionalExpression[1/4 (6 + 2 a + b + 3 c), 
    1/4 (-2 a - b - 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (1 - 2 a - b - 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (3 - 2 a - b - 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (6 + 2 a + b + 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (9 - 12 a + 2 b + 6 c) \[NotElement] Integers], 
  s -> ConditionalExpression[1/4 (1 - 2 a - b - 3 c), 
    1/4 (-2 a - b - 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (1 - 2 a - b - 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (3 - 2 a - b - 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (6 + 2 a + b + 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (9 - 12 a + 2 b + 6 c) \[NotElement] Integers], 
  t -> ConditionalExpression[1/4 (3 - 2 a - b - 3 c), 
    1/4 (-2 a - b - 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (1 - 2 a - b - 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (3 - 2 a - b - 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (6 + 2 a + b + 3 c) \[NotElement] Integers && 
     1/4 (9 - 12 a + 2 b + 6 c) \[NotElement] Integers]}}
*)
```

The conditions in these `ConditionalExpression`s are the same for each variable

```
SameQ @@ firstsol[[1, ;; , 2, 2]]
(* True *)
```

So let's see if we can find some integers `a`, `b` and `c` that satisfy them

```
FindInstance[firstsol[[1, 1, 2, 2]], {a, b, c}, Integers]

(* {} *)
```

No we can't. Therefore, there are no solutions.